# How to have HTML navigation bar stay the same, even if the webpage is too small

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar, but when the page is resized too small the navigation bar extends to a second line below it. I'd like it so even when the webpage is resized, the navbar stays the exact same (same size and everything). Here is some of my CSS that has to do with the navbar:

```
nav ul {
  margin-top:-200px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}
nav ul li {
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  left: 5;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul ul li {
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 10px;
}
nav ul li:hover ul {
  color: #4169E1;
  display: block;
}
```

SCREENSHOT: http://gyazo.com/86c490863c3f1149098b6600c1ab276b

Comment: Can you put a screen shot?

Comment: Set you navigation to relative position and float to left. Just like [this](http://stmikibbi.ac.id/online) perhaps?

Comment: I added the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one more line of css

```
nav {
  min-width: 800px; 
  max-width: 1200px;
}
```

Comment: You might also want to add "white-space: nowrap".

Answer (score 1):

Add a `min-width` to your navigation bar to force it to maintain a certain length. Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t8h50p2g/1/

```
nav {
min-width: 1000px;
}
```